# Center Div's within another Div

Tags: html, css

I am trying to center 8 div's which are inside another div.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<div align="center" id="buttonBar">
    <div class="menuButton">
        <a href="link" class="menuButtonText">Home</a>
    </div>
    <div class="menuButton">
        <a href="link" class="menuButtonText">Author</a>
    </div>
    <div class="menuButton">
        <a href="link" class="menuButtonText">Literature</a>
    </div>
    <div class="menuButton">
        <a href="link" class="menuButtonText">Projects</a>
    </div>
    <div class="menuButton">
        <a href="link" class="menuButtonText">Pictures</a>
    </div>
    <div class="menuButton">
        <a href="link" class="menuButtonText">How To...</a>
    </div>
    <div class="menuButton">
        <a href="link" class="menuButtonText">Updater</a>
    </div>
    <div class="menuButton">
        <a href="link" class="menuButtonText">Copyright</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is my CSS:

```
#buttonBar {
    padding-left: 50px;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}
.menuButton {
    height: 50px;
    width: 125px;
    background-color: lightblue;
    display:inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 50px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
.menuButtonText {
    font-size: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 50px;
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```css
#buttonBar {
  padding-left: 50px;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}
.menuButton {
  height: 50px;
  width: 125px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
.menuButtonText {
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div align="center" id="buttonBar">
  <div class="menuButton">
    <a href="link" class="menuButtonText">Home</a>

  </div>
  <div class="menuButton">
    <a href="link" class="menuButtonText">Author</a>

  </div>
  <div class="menuButton">
    <a href="link" class="menuButtonText">Literature</a>

  </div>
  <div class="menuButton">
    <a href="link" class="menuButtonText">Projects</a>

  </div>
  <div class="menuButton">
    <a href="link" class="menuButtonText">Pictures</a>

  </div>
  <div class="menuButton">
    <a href="link" class="menuButtonText">How To...</a>

  </div>
  <div class="menuButton">
    <a href="link" class="menuButtonText">Updater</a>

  </div>
  <div class="menuButton">
    <a href="link" class="menuButtonText">Copyright</a>

  </div>
</div>
```

The addition of the `align:center` and setting `margin-left` and `margin-right` to auto, did move my div's, but not in the center. It moved the div's more towards the right. Is there something I am doing wrong?

Comment: As a side note, I did test this in Chrome and IE, and got the same results (div's more right, not centered).

Comment: Please put this in JSFiddle

Comment: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3k22fxos/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try taking the `padding-left: 50px` out of `#buttonBar`.

```
#buttonBar {
    padding-left: 50px;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}
```

should be

```
#buttonBar {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}
```

I think that is what was pushing it to the right.

Comment: Yep that fixed it. Don't know how I missed that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For all divs
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: auto ;
    margin-right: auto ;

http://www.thesitewizard.com/css/center-div-block.shtml

Comment: He can't do that because he has many divs aligned side by side, not in block format. So giving them all a width of 100% would put that off. He was on the right track with the `display: inline-block;`